# Replace enum by class inTemplates c++

Tags: c++, templates, enums

i'm facing following problem. Say you have some deeper inheritance. here is some pseudo code:

```
class MeshEntity{ } // some entities are mesh entities
class SingleMeshEntity : MeshEntity { } // some entites use single meshes
class MultiMeshEntity  : MeshEntity { } // some entities use multi meshes

template <class BASE> class CollisionMeshEntity : BASE // base is either SingleMeshEntity or MultiMeshEntity
```

Lets say you have some enum:

```
enum MESH_TYPE
{
     SINGLE,
     MULTI
}
```

Is it possible to create a template that uses following template (pseude code):

```
template<MESH_TYPE T> CollisionMeshEntity : if(T == SINGLE){SingleMeshEntity } else if (T == MULTI) {MultiMeshEntity}
```

The above code is much simplified. In my programm i have more situations like this, and also the same problem in deeper inheritances.

My aim is to finally create a simple Template that takes two or more enums and then added all correct inheritances up to all base classes.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `std::conditional` from `<type_traits>`.

The way it works is very simple:

`std::conditional<true, int, float>::type` means `int`.

`std::conditional<false, int, float>::type` means `float`.

Thus, it substitutes one of two types based on a value of the first parameter.

Keep in mind that in some contexts compiler will require you to put `typename` keyword right before `std::conditional<..>`.

---

Implementing a class that chooses it's base depending on a constexpr value is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your and all other ansers. That is exactly what i was looking for. Because all answers are correct, i take the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::conditional` for this:

```
template <MESH_TYPE Base> class CollisionMeshEntity 
    : std::conditional_t<(Base == SINGLE), SingleMeshEntity, MultiMeshEntity>
{};
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do something like the following.

Starting with your basic classes:

```
#include <type_traits>

class MeshEntity{ }; // some entities are mesh entities
class SingleMeshEntity : MeshEntity { }; // some entites use single meshes
class MultiMeshEntity  : MeshEntity { }; // some entities use multi meshes
```

and enum:

```
enum MESH_TYPE
{
    SINGLE,
    MULTI
};
```

define the following helper struct:

```
template<MESH_TYPE MeshType>
struct mesh_type
{
    typedef 
        typename std::conditional<
            MeshType == SINGLE,
            SingleMeshEntity,
            MultiMeshEntity>::type
        type;
};
```

you can now use it almost like any type; for inheritance:

```
class foo :
    public mesh_type<SINGLE>::type
{};
```

or for defining objects:

```
int main()
{
    mesh_type<SINGLE>::type t0;
}
```